# Nginx if-directive condition based on upstream fallback?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have just passive health-checks on some upstream servers.  If they fall back to backup server, I need a way to act differently in the server block (with an if condition).  Is there some technique or direct state variable available that can either indicate that availability status or maybe just tell which actual upstream server has been selected for a request?

I need my rewrite rule to be a little different based on whether a preferred upstream is unavailable and falling back to a backup server.

Basically, I want to forward the entire request as-is to another reverse-proxy for handling the request if the individual upstream service I prefer to use for a normally reverse-proxied route is unavailable.